# Reachable break statement within a try block

Tags: java

**[JLS 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)** gives a description for some `Unreachable statements`. In particular it says:

> A reachable break statement exits a statement if, within the break
>   target, either there are no try statements whose try blocks contain
>   the break statement, or there are try statements whose try blocks
>   contain the break statement and all finally clauses of those try
>   statements can complete normally.

I'm trying to discover that rule by example. I've written the following simple test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    while (true) {
        try {                      //Try statement which contains a break statement.
            break;
        } 
        finally {                //Finally always complete abruptly 
            throw new Exception(); //because of throwing an exception.
        }

        try {                      //Compile-time error: Unreachable statement
        } 
        finally {                //That finally doesn't contain any instruction. 
            //It always complete normally.
        }
    }
}
```

I don't find something strange in that behavior except for that exception is thrown in the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    while (true) {
        try {
            break;
        } 
        finally {
            throw new Exception(); //Run-time error due to throwing an exception.
        }
    }
}
```

What is that rule actual about?

Comment: You find it strange that the exception gets thrown? `and all finally clauses of those try statements can complete normally` that describes this behavior.

Comment: @Tom Yes, I do. The thing is break statement must must immediately complete normally nearest enclosing while, do, for or switch statement (JLS 14.15).  That's finally block must not be executed.

Comment: If all finally blocks complete normally. Does that your finally block in your second example?

Comment: @Tom But if we put something into the finally block we'll get a compile-time error. http://ideone.com/xInSBL . That's the break stetament exits from the try block and attemps to transfer control to the finally block.

Comment: Sure you're getting an error there. The `try` block exists after the `break` statement and the finally block will be executed then. So the console print won't be reached. The `break` statement stops the execution of the `try` block and also stops the nearest loop, but it does not prevent the `finally` block to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If control flow runs into the `try` part of a `try` / `finally` block, then the `finally` part will *always* run. (This is very useful for immediate cleanup of resources where it would be unwise to rely on the garbage collector.)

The only exception is a call in the `try` part which shuts down the JVM. For example `System.exit(...)`.

In your case, program flow can never reach the second `try`, so the second `finally` is therefore also unreachable.

Comment: I just have found that it looks contradictory. Because JLS said that the break stetament completed the while statement immediately. Meanwhile finally block will always be executed.

Comment: It does complete the `while` immediately, but the `finally` will still run since `try` has been entered.

Comment: As far as I've understood what you said we must mention about the break statement as the statement containing into the `try`-block and then satisfies to all rules about the try statement. In particular, after the while statement has been competed JVM attemps to transfer control to the `finally` statement, does it?

Comment: That's almost correct: any variable defined in the scope of the `while` is accessible in the `finally`. So think in terms of the `finally` statement running *just* before the closing brace of the `while` loop.

Comment: That's not quite clear. In the case execution of the break statement, which completes abruptly itself, includes attemping to transfer control to the nearest enclosing while and completes the while normally. Now, following by JLS 14.20 the control is transfered to the finally statement. Why not?